# Patching an installation using a bundle oder msi?

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer, bundle, patch

I have no experience in patching/upgrading an installation.

We have a wix bundle setup with a standard (wix-created) msi inside which is added to the bundle this way:

```
<MsiPackage SourceFile="MySetup.msi" Id="MySetupId" Cache="yes" DisplayInternalUI="no" SuppressSignatureVerification ="yes" Visible="no" >
```

so in Add/Remove software section there is the bundle shown, not the msi itself.

Both, the msi and the bundle, are signed.

Currently our released version is "2.1.0.BuildNumber".

The bundle.wxs has upgrade code A
The msi has product code B and upgrade code C.

Unfortunately this version contains a mean bug but we don't want to release "v2.2.0.BuildNumber" just because of this bug, but "2.1.1.BuildNumber", so we need a patch.

What is be best practise here? Should we just create a msp file described like here

http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/patching/wix_patching.html?

Will this break the relationship between the bundle and the msi? Will this patch be shown in Add/Remove programms section?

Or is there a possibility to use the bundle for a patch?

Goal is, that our customers just can install the patch without deinstalling the old version, but can deinstall the whole scope using the formerly released bundle.

Comment: What is your motivation to create a patch instead of regular package?  In the old days of CDs/DVDs and slow internet the motivation was that the patch contained only changes and was much smaller than the main package.  Is it still a concern for your product?

Comment: Another motivation was that the package version remains the same.  But you suggest to change it: main package 2.2.0, new package 2.2.1 is a new package version that may be installed as new version of the package and not a patch.

Comment: Finally, "can deinstall using the formerly released bundle" is somewhat artificial if the users can uninstall the currently installed version from ARP or using the latest, currently installed installation package.

Comment: Our installation contains several baggage like html files and some zips which remain unchanged. Thats why we would like only to deploy our changed binaries, basically some dlls. The increase of the version number is not mandatory, but right now our products version is the same as the build version of our binaries. I think I don't understood your last point. In ARP there is right now only the bundle, not the real installed msi visible. So when the patch has been applied still the only way to remove the whole files is using the ARP entry of the bundle or the bundle.exe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My personal advice is do not create patches unless absolutely necessary.  You avoid a lot of trouble.  The main problem IMO is that patches do not fit well onto source control and CI.  First, you are not able to automatically increase the build number and include it into version number - it must remain the same.  Second, creating an msp patch requires the binaries from the previous build be present during the new build.  In MS technology the previous msi should be present, in WiX technology you cited you will need *.wixpdb from the previous build.  Third (or the first?), the patch is a one-time action which should not be automated for continuous execution by CI.

If the bundle does not include its packages into exe but download them, a new bundle version can download only changed packages so that installation time will be small.  Otherwise you are out of luck.

You need to create an msp upgrade for your buggy msi.  The upgrade may or may not change the msi version, but if it does then the version of msi will not match the version of the bundle.  User does not see msi version anyway.

You can install msp directly.  When the bundle is uninstalled, msp will be uninstalled too.  I do not know whether the msp will be visible in ARP (msi is not visible).

You may create a patch bundle.  This is an independent bundle with its own upgrade code.  It will contain

```
<Bundle .... ParentName="Name of your main bundle"...>
    <RelatedBundle Id="YourMainBundleUpgradeCode" Action="Patch" />
```

Include MspPackage with your msp into the Chain.

This bundle will be visible in Installed Updates as a child of "Name of your main bundle" and it will be uninstalled with the main bundle or when a new version of the main bundle is installed.

You will also need to include a Condition to prevent installation of patch bundle when the main bundle of this particular version is not installed.  There is no documented API to detect bundles (although you may use a RegistrySearch), but you may do ProductSearch for particular version of your msi included in main bundle.

Note that a new release of the main bundle with the same version number will install in parallel (there will be two identical entries in ARP) and new release with greater version number will automatically uninstall previous release.  Thus, you cannot make new release of the main bundle.

Comment: Unfortunately we did something wrong in the c# code of the bundle. Applying an MSP directly worked fine, regardeless that the bundle version in ARP is not the correct anymore. We have code in our bundle which aborts the setup when PackageState.Superseded, so I can't deinstall the application using our bundle. I try your second suggestion. The patch bundle must not have the same upgrade code than the main bundle, right? @dvom:"Note that a new release of the main bundle with the same version number" means same version number of the patch bundle? This we will prevent.

Comment: You've got another argument against patching.  Conventional installer wisdom says your 1.0 installer not ready until you prepared and tested 1.1.  In your case, prepared and tested a patch :(

Comment: Patch bundle may work if burn engine uninstalls the patch bundle first.  Hopefully this is the case, I just do not know.  Also, make sure your msp patch is uninstallable (check documentation).  If the only changes are new dll version, it should be OK.

Comment: When the patch bundle is being uninstalled from APR it removes first the msp and then the main bundle, so at least ust one click, which is fine. When trying to uninstall the main bundle it still is showing the error due to supersedeness, but this is something we could accept. Now I have to figure out how to prevent the patch bundle form installation when the related main bundle is missing ,-) Thank you for your help, you saved my Easter.

Comment: @Torben-TSC http://howdididothatthingagain.blogspot.com/2013/06/conditioning-wix-bundle-when-it-should.html

Comment: And do not forget yet another scenario - installing new version of main bundle on top of current main bundle with a patch.

Comment: This is quite a tricky issue. I configured my bundle patch only to be installed when I found my specific version to be patched to prevent it from beeing installed over other versions with the same product code (eben when we released just one version, but we had a semi-open test phase so there are possibly other version outside) This works fine until I try to uninstall the patch. Then my condition evaluates to false and I can't deinstall the neither the bundle patch nor the bundle itself.It should have a condition which evaluates if the patch is installed.

Comment: Did you followed the link I provided?

Comment: Yes, Id did - sorry for the delayed answer.I think that our setup is very bad designed in several points so i run from one problem into another. Basically I broke the handling of command-line arguments as well as the handling of the Detection-Events which results in strange behaviour. I would like to explain the structure of my solution. I appreciate your help very much

Comment: To be more precise I tried your link and after some struggeling it works fine, technically. But since I have wrong code in my MainViewModel in the Detection-Events my custom ui causes the malfunction since my setup recognizes that this specific bundle was not responsible for that (patched) installation and my code brought the error page to front. I tried to specify my issues more detailed in another question since this one is answered. With your help I can finally patch - if only my setup would be well formed ;-)